# Flag the previous columns based on condition met in current column in SAS

Tags: performance, sorting, sas, row, lag

For above table write a SAS Code for above  table with following instruction:

1. Create a new column ABCFlag and
2. Identify a row where value in column "TreatmentChangeCD" is R and value in column "diff_visit" is less than 90,
   3.Start traversing above from identified row and find the first occurrence of ACTIVE_CHRONIC_POST_TX = 1 , where value of "Pat" is same
3. add a value 2 in ABCFlag column for a row
4. repeat this for all values in  "FirstName_ORRS"

Sample table in figure

My goal is to find the end date for the transplant period if the patient changed modality  after transplant and not recovered within 90days.

Comment: Please post sample data in `datalines` format or in a text table. Please do not post a screenshot of your data or code.